# Как убрать уведомление о загрузке pip package updater в VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, pip

При старте Visual Studio Code, после того как загрузятся основные плагины выводится в нижней панели это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как избавиться от этого уведомления? Приходится всё время это переключать на терминал, неудобно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не заметил и случайно установил плагин `pip-packages`. Я его удалил и перестало появляться уведомление при старте VSCode

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]